# data-at-rest encryption for NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

Prototyping a project with Mongo & Spring Boot and thinking it does a lot of what I want. However, I really need to have encrypted data-at-rest, which would seem to indicate I have to purchase the enterprise version.  Since I don't have a budget yet, I am wondering if there is another alternative that people have found useful? I think DynamoDB can be used in a local & test environment.  Or it viable to encrypt the data at the application level and still have great performance for my CRUD operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done application level encryption with DynamoDB before with some success. My issues where not really with DynamoDB but with the encryption in the application.

First, encryption/decryption is very expensive. I had to increase the number of servers I was using by over double just to handle the extra CPU load. Your milage may very. In my case, I was using Node.js and the servers suddenly switched from being I/O bound to being CPU bound.

Second, doing encryption/decryption application side adds a lot of complexity to your app. You will almost certainly need to parallelize the encryption/decryption to minimize the added latency that it will cause. Also, you will need to figure out a secure way of sharing the keys.

Last, application level encryption will make some DynamoDB operations unavailable to you. For example, [conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html) probably won't make sense anymore for encrypted values.

Long story short, I wouldn't recommend application level encryption regardless of the database.

DynamoDB now supports what they call Server-Side Encryption at Rest. Personally I think that name is a little confusing but from their perspective, your application is the client and DynamoDB is the server.

> Amazon DynamoDB encryption at rest helps you secure your application
>   data in Amazon DynamoDB tables further using AWS-managed encryption
>   keys stored in AWS Key Management Service (KMS). Encryption at rest is
>   fully transparent to the user with all DynamoDB queries working
>   seamlessly on encrypted data. With this new capability, it has never
>   been easier to use DynamoDB for security-sensitive applications with
>   strict encryption compliance and regulatory requirements.

[Blog post about DynamoDB encryption at rest](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-encryption-at-rest-for-dynamodb/)

> You simply enable encryption when you create a new table and DynamoDB
>   takes care of the rest. Your data (tables, local secondary indexes,
>   and global secondary indexes) will be encrypted using AES-256 and a
>   service-default AWS Key Management Service (KMS) key. The encryption
>   adds no storage overhead and is completely transparent; you can
>   insert, query, scan, and delete items as before. The team did not
>   observe any changes in latency after enabling encryption and running
>   several different workloads on an encrypted DynamoDB table.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough feedback!  I have been looking at DynamoDB running locally to compare with MongoDB locally.  While I won't be able to compare encryption (or at least I don't think I can) I guess knowing that both databases support encryption will help me pick one.

Comment: Happy I could help!